Is one hour enough for international transfer in Brisbane?
I booked a flight from Auckland to Tokyo with JetStar, carry on baggage only, and I did not notice that the connection at Brisbane is 60 minutes only. The passenger will be traveling on a New Zealand passport, is this time between arrival and departure enough?

FYI: Which airport has the longest minimum connection time?

What if your flight is late?   One hour is pretty short for any international transfer.

@Kingsley, comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post, how do you suggest I improve it?

Assuming this is a single ticket (which is likely) you have a very good chance of making it. You do not need to clear any type of immigration or customs in Brisbane. You may have to go through transfer security (hard to tell) but otherwise  you just get off your incoming flight and walk over to your departure gate.
If you miss the connecting (by no fault of your own), JetStar will rebook you for free on the next flight to TOK.
If these are two separate tickets, there is no way you can make this.

The Brisbane airport website says that as long as you are checked through “after exiting your aircraft, follow the ‘International Transit/Transfer Passenger' signs and make your way to the Level 3 ‘Departures Area’ to board your next flight.” not sure whether there’s no security or if they think it’s so obvious they don’t need to mention it.

What's Brisbane airport like these days ?

All passengers transiting an Australian international airport are required to clear security.  Generally this is quick, but it can depend how many/which flights arrived before yours.

The Brisbane Airport map for the international terminal indicates that all gates are connected on the air-side, however, under Australian law, (see point 6), all passengers must be cleared before re-embarking a plane. It seems that this is on a special international transit route within the international terminal from the level 2 arrivals, so no need to go through passport control/immigration.
In addition the airport information has this to say on transferring between flights:

Where do I go if I am in international transit?
Transiting between international flights in Brisbane is simple - you won't even need to leave the International Terminal. The process for connecting with your flight  will depend on the airline or airlines you are travelling with, so check with your airline or travel agent regarding any visa requirements and to understand if you need to check in for your next flight.
Do I need a transit visa?
Some passengers may be eligible to transit without a visa, if they meet all of the eligibility criteria. To find out if you are eligible to transit without a visa, visit the Department of Home Affairs website.
Passengers who do not meet the criteria, or need to collect luggage and check-in for their next international flight, will need to apply for a Transit Visa.  Visit the Department of Home Affairs website to apply for a transit visa.
Passengers with onward boarding passes with the same/partner airline
If your luggage is checked through to your next international destination and your airline has issued you with your boarding pass, after exiting your aircraft, follow the ‘International Transit/Transfer Passenger' signs and make your way to the Level 3 ‘Departures Area’ to board your next flight.
Passengers travelling on a different airline, needing to check-in for their next flight
If your bags are not checked through to your next international destination, you will be required to go through Passport Control, collect your luggage and make your way to Departures on Level 4 to check-in for your next flight. Follow the signs to Passport Control and Baggage Claim.
We recommend you check with your airline or travel agent about visa requirements as every situation is different.

If you were to have check-in luggage, you should check your ticket to ensure that your flight does indeed transfer baggage through to Tokyo (i.e. single ticket; I can see flights on Jetstar from Auckland to Tokyo, so it is possible that this is the case), but if not, you will need to go through passport control and check in again at the departures check-in and pass through the main security again.
You should check to see that you meet the Transit Without a Visa requirements (TWOV), as Australia does require transfer visas for some nationalities.
Brisbane does have the facilities for TWOV; however if you don't meet the requirements, you can find more information about a transit visa at the Subclass 771 Transit Visa webpage.
If you do need to go through passport control at any point, then 60 min is not enough. Otherwise, assuming your flight is on time, and single ticket, 60 min should be plenty, though with the security clearing needed, it may take longer depending on the number of people also using the international transit facility.

The OP stated "carry on baggage only"

@PeterM Indeed, however I thought the policy was to make answers that would suit generalities - in this case Brisbane Airport. Doesn't make much sense to have an answer that just covers the situation with no checked baggage and have a separate one for checked baggage. In this case carry-on ~= checked through baggage.

@PeterM even with carry on only, there are situations where one may need to go reach a check-in desk and thus have to go through passport control (no online check-in and inability to use transfer desks or kiosks, documents check…). Also the first airline may require the passenger to ave the necessary paperwork to enter the transit country (if it is indeed a self-transfer, which I hope this isn’t).

This answer is wrong.  All passengers transiting Australian International airports are required to re-clear security.  There is no need to clear immigration.

@bob1 There is a difference between generalities and presenting advice that is irrelevant.  The OP stated that they only have hand luggage, but you have a whole paragraph that starts off "You should check your ticket to ensure that your flight does indeed transfer baggage ..".  I would feel differently if this information was in an addendum that started off like "BTW even though you don't have checked luggage, if you do then blah blah blah".   In that way you are differentiating between the exact case of the OP (and hence the information that they want), and the overall general case.

@bob1 Or to put it an another way.  The OP wants answers to their specific problem.  That information should be clearly and accurately expressed.  Once that is done you can provide additional information as you see fit, but it should be obvious that this information doesn't necessarily apply to the OP's situation.

@Doc There's nothing about security in the airport page information on transit. However, it does appear in the laws. Amended.

@PeterM Fair enough. I've fixed it to read "if you were to have..."
